# Quand un pluriel est singulier

Tags: grammaire, pluriel

Je ne suis pas à l'aise avec les phrases où un pluriel "est" un singulier, comme par exemple:

> Des résultats positifs dans ce sens seraient une révolution du domaine.

Ici le sujet est au pluriel, le verbe est être, et le complément est au singulier.
On a donc littéralement un pluriel qui est un singulier, ce qui sonne un peu faux...

Y a-t-il une règle grammaticale particulière à respecter dans ce genre de cas ?

Comment: Si on veut être précis, "une révolution du domaine" est un attribut du sujet, pas un complément.

Answer (score 2):

Une formulation grammatique serait de voir un mot imaginaire, comme *ensemble*, modifier le verbe, comme

> Des résultats positifs dans ce sens seraient [ensemble] une révolution du domaine.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas de règle qui "interdirait" un tel usage. La seule règle qui pourrait s'en approcher est la règle de l'accord de l'adjectif ou participe passé utilisé comme attribut du sujet - mais elle ne s'applique pas aux noms.

Par ailleurs, pour ce qui concerne le style plus que la grammaire, on conseille souvent, à l'écrit, d'éviter le verbe "être" et d'y substituer un verbe plus précis.
On pourrait alors écrire par exemple:

> Des résultats positifs dans ce sens constitueraient une révolution du domaine

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a aucun problème avec cette phrase. La règle grammaticale, pour une fois, est simple : le verbe s'accorde avec son sujet.

On trouve beaucoup d'exemples sur le web de ce type de formulation :

> Les enfants sont un trésor
>
> Les transports en commun sont un service essentiel
>
> Les tomates sont un délice